# Where to find identifier and secret for OAuth2.0 and what does 'imaginary functions' mean?

Tags: android, dart, flutter, oauth-2.0

I'm following this [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/oauth2#-readme-tab-) to implement OAuth2.0 in my flutter app and don't understand a few things, here is the code from the documentation:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:oauth2/oauth2.dart' as oauth2;

// These URLs are endpoints that are provided by the authorization
// server. They're usually included in the server's documentation of its
// OAuth2 API.
final authorizationEndpoint =
    Uri.parse("http://example.com/oauth2/authorization");
final tokenEndpoint =
    Uri.parse("http://example.com/oauth2/token");

// The authorization server will issue each client a separate client
// identifier and secret, which allows the server to tell which client
// is accessing it. Some servers may also have an anonymous
// identifier/secret pair that any client may use.
//
// Note that clients whose source code or binary executable is readily
// available may not be able to make sure the client secret is kept a
// secret. This is fine; OAuth2 servers generally won't rely on knowing
// with certainty that a client is who it claims to be.
final identifier = "my client identifier";
final secret = "my client secret";

// This is a URL on your application's server. The authorization server
// will redirect the resource owner here once they've authorized the
// client. The redirection will include the authorization code in the
// query parameters.
final redirectUrl = Uri.parse("http://my-site.com/oauth2-redirect");

/// A file in which the users credentials are stored persistently. If the server
/// issues a refresh token allowing the client to refresh outdated credentials,
/// these may be valid indefinitely, meaning the user never has to
/// re-authenticate.
final credentialsFile = new File("~/.myapp/credentials.json");

/// Either load an OAuth2 client from saved credentials or authenticate a new
/// one.
Future<oauth2.Client> getClient() async {
  var exists = await credentialsFile.exists();

  // If the OAuth2 credentials have already been saved from a previous run, we
  // just want to reload them.
  if (exists) {
    var credentials = new oauth2.Credentials.fromJson(
        await credentialsFile.readAsString());
    return new oauth2.Client(credentials,
        identifier: identifier, secret: secret);
  }

  // If we don't have OAuth2 credentials yet, we need to get the resource owner
  // to authorize us. We're assuming here that we're a command-line application.
  var grant = new oauth2.AuthorizationCodeGrant(
      identifier, authorizationEndpoint, tokenEndpoint,
      secret: secret);

  // Redirect the resource owner to the authorization URL. This will be a URL on
  // the authorization server (authorizationEndpoint with some additional query
  // parameters). Once the resource owner has authorized, they'll be redirected
  // to `redirectUrl` with an authorization code.
  //
  // `redirect` is an imaginary function that redirects the resource
  // owner's browser.
  await redirect(grant.getAuthorizationUrl(redirectUrl));

  // Another imaginary function that listens for a request to `redirectUrl`.
  var request = await listen(redirectUrl);

  // Once the user is redirected to `redirectUrl`, pass the query parameters to
  // the AuthorizationCodeGrant. It will validate them and extract the
  // authorization code to create a new Client.
  return await grant.handleAuthorizationResponse(request.uri.queryParameters);
}

main() async {
  var client = await loadClient();

  // Once you have a Client, you can use it just like any other HTTP client.
  var result = client.read("http://example.com/protected-resources.txt");

  // Once we're done with the client, save the credentials file. This ensures
  // that if the credentials were automatically refreshed while using the
  // client, the new credentials are available for the next run of the
  // program.
  await credentialsFile.writeAsString(client.credentials.toJson());

  print(result);
}
```

Where can I find the identifier and secret ? Is it shown in the /.well-known/openid-configuration page ? Also how do I implement these functions:

```dart
await redirect(grant.getAuthorizationUrl(redirectUrl));
var request = await listen(redirectUrl);
var client = await loadClient();
```

The documentation mentions that it is an imaginary function. How do I implement those functions?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OAuth with flutter is never going to be completely straight-forward on Android or iOS because it lacks deep integration with the OS, so you'll have to do a bit of per-OS configuration. And to be completely honest, it's not all that easy in native Android/iOS either.

And that plugin you're looking at seems much more focused towards a server application, which is why it doesn't make complete sense to a flutter developer. However, it isn't impossible to use it!

The main thing that enables OAuth to work is using either a Custom Url Scheme or a Universal Link. A Custom Url Scheme is something like com.myapp.customurlscheme:// - it's used instead of 'https'. A Universal link uses https and a website i.e. https://myapp.com/customurl/. An important difference is that to use a Universal link, you must control the website and upload a file that apple can check to know you've given the app permission to replace that website or that part of the website. If the user has the app installed, they will be shown it when they go to that url; if they don't, they'll be shown something by the website (normally a link to install the app).

In the case where you're an authenticating client with OAuth, you normally don't want to be replicating part of a website as all you're doing is making a callback (redirect) url, so you'll probably be using a custom url scheme. This has to be done by adding to either your AndroidManifest.xml or Info.plist files.

For iOS's Info.plist that looks something like:

```xml
  <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
      <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
      <string>Editor</string>
      <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
      <string>[ANY_URL_NAME]</string>
      <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
      <array>
        <string>[YOUR_SCHEME]</string>
      </array>
    </dict>
  </array>
```

And for the AndroidManifest.xml something like:

```xml
    <activity>
       
      ...
   
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data
          android:scheme="[YOUR_SCHEME]"
          android:host="[YOUR_HOST]" />
      </intent-filter>
```

Once you have that set up, you can add listeners natively for when the app is 'opened' with one of those custom URLs. That's a bit of a pain, but thankfully someone has made a plugin that helps: [Universal Links](https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links) (and credit to them for the sample config above as I shamelessly stole it from their documentation). You can use its `getInitialLink()` method in your main function (or somewhere like it) and/or get a stream of links to listen for using `getLinksStream()`. I think that the second one is what you'll be using since the app is open already when you start the OAuth/OpenID workflow - so you'll start listening either right after the app is opened, or right before you start with the OAuth call.

Okay, so that was a lot. There's a reason for it though - what this has done is made a way for your app to receive redirects from a browser or other app. So if you handle that `getLinksStream`, you can then more or less receive a callback from the oauth2 server. You could set up some system where you create a future that waits for a particular link being passed through the linkstream.

So that covers

> `// Another imaginary function that listens for a request to 'redirectUrl'.`
>
> `var request = await listen(redirectUrl);`

Now we need to do something about that first `imaginary function`. Turns out in the app case, it's not imaginary at all - you need to launch that URL rather than having the page redirect as it would on a server. There's a plugin for that: [Url Launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher)

So where it's saying `await redirect(grant.getAuthorizationUrl(redirectUrl));`, what you actually want to be doing is launching `grant.getAuthorizationUrl` with url_launcher's `launch()` (with appropriate flags, that you'll have to figure out by testing. You may want to force using a browser, or not, depending on whether the OAuth server has an app that can handle auth for it. If they do, you probably want the url to open up in their app so the user is already logged in).

There's a couple more pieces to this puzzle that need to be fit in. The first is the `redirectUrl` that you have to pass into `getAuthorizationUrl`. What do I put in there, you ask?! Well, you use that nifty custom app scheme we set up earlier! So the redirect url will be something like com.myapp.customurlscheme://customurlredirect.

So the OAuth token provisioning workflow goes something like this:

- you launch the auth url for the server
- a login page is shown to the user, or a permissions page, or whatever the server does
- once the user has approved the request, the server redirects the user back to your app (it might ask them "Do you want to open in " or something like it).
- Your app receives the callback with the authorization code
- Your app should request tokens using that authorization code (I assume that's handled by handleAuthorizationResponse).

---

Now, before you implement all that, there are a few things to think about.

1. If this were a server application, you could have a secure secret which proves to the OAuth server that your application is the client it claims to be. You would get that from the OAuth server and provision it directly to the server. However, because you're writing an app there is no (easy) way to provision that secure secret. So instead of using the normal OAuth you should be the OAuth authorization code flow with PKCE, and no client_secret. If that went over your head, you should do some reading up on PKCE - Auth0 has a [good  writeup](https://auth0.com/docs/flows/concepts/auth-code-pkce). The OAuth server you're working with also has to support that, but if you do this without it your login process will be insecure.
2. The OAuth server you're communicating with has to both understand and accept custom url schemes. Most of the big ones do and they actually have documentation similar to this which should walk you through the same process (but not flutter-specific). And in fact they actually define what the custom url schemes should be - in Facebook's case if your app id is `1234567` then the custom url scheme would be something like `fb1234567://`.
3. I haven't looked that much into that library you're using, but you may want to make sure it actually supports the right OAuth workflow. If it designed as a server-side package as I suspect, it might not. In that case you might have to manually do the setup - which realistically isn't that difficult, you just have to generate a couple of URLs to match what the OAuth server expects which is pretty well documented and standardized.

That was a lot of information, but unfortunately OAuth2 isn't all that simple (and realistically, it can't be all that much simpler if it is to do what it needs to do). Good luck with your app!